# How to pass extra props to new page through <Link> with React-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a new page that's rendered and accessed through a `<Link>` that's being passed a `bookName` and `bookEdition`. This works fine, great.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/book/:bookName/:bookEdition" component={Book}/>
</Router>

<Link to={"/book/ReactJS For Dummies/1st Edition"}><p>Link here</p></Link>
```

However, I want to pass additional context data about the book and the search results it was found in to the new page, through a prop or something. I've tried something like this to no avail:

```
<Link to={"/book/ReactJS For Dummies/1st Edition"} params={{hits:hit}}><p>Link here</p></Link>
```

I know I can add additional data to the `<Route>` component, as `hits={hit}`, but that's out of scope for the data that I need to pass through. It needs to be passed through where the `<Link>` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass those additional props as query parameters.

```
<Link to={"/book/ReactJS For Dummies/1st Edition"} query={{hits: hits}}><p>Link here</p></Link>
```

You can then access these values inside your `Book` component from `this.props.location.query`

**Update**

Since passing query params as `query` prop has been deprecated in React-Router v2, you can instead pass it like this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/book/ReactJS For Dummies/1st Edition", query: {hits: hits} }}><p>Link here</p></Link>
```

Comment: Ok, that works; it wants strings though so passing my object through is a little bulky. However it's also telling me `query` is deprecated so I'm passing it through the `to` param as listed here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors

Comment: Yes, I didn't realise that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, I just realised this pastes all the data into the URL too... that's not gonna work for me, it's a lot of data I'm passing around.

Comment: Just as Krasimir mentioned, you shouldn't be passing all that data through a `Link`. It would be better to store it somewhere as a state. `Link` is simply a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

The router in your app is not designed for passing such data. My experience shows me that this is a bad approach. If you are app needs to transfer information from one page to another the URL is definitely not a good place for that. It simply doesn't scale. I guess you are using flux (or redux) so manage that use case in your app state. Dispatch a dedicated action and keep that data so you can consume it later.

Answer (score 0):

In React Router v6 you can pass [state](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#state) without using query params:

```
<Link to={"/book/ReactJS For Dummies/1st Edition"} state={{hits:hit}}><p>Link here</p></Link>
```

Which you can then get in the component using:

```
let { state } = useLocation();
```